# Schema Compare Visual Studio 2010 - adding new object do database project to main directory

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, database-project, database-comparison

During conversion old, 2008 database project into 2010 database project using features like Partial Project reference, I encounter problem with Schema Compare in VS 2010. After successful merge new object from DB into DB project, files are being added into the root directory of database project, but it should be added into to existing Schema Objects structure.

Any ideas, how solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used simple workaround: creating project from scrach, attach all partial projects and merge all objects from DB into DB proj - same effect can be acquired by manual creation of the .dbproj file.

It is high probability, that it was configuration issue located in .dbproj file and was caused by upgrade DB proj from VS 9 -> V10.